# Spring boot 2 and ReadinessProbe / LivenessProbe

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

How can I configure my Deployment to do a health check on the sprint boot actuator endpoint?
I'm using spring boot 2 running on port 9000. (PS: port-forward test works)

This is the error:

```
Readiness probe failed: Get http://10.48.0.116:9000/actuator/health: dial tcp 10.48.0.116:9000: connect: connection refused
```

And that is my Deployment yml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-api
  namespace: vidolin
  labels:
    stack: api
    app: my-api
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      stack: api
      app: my-api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        stack: api
        app: my-api
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:  
      - name: itdevregistry
      containers:
      - name: primary
        image: vidolinregistry.azurecr.io/my/api
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: my-api-config
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /actuator/health
            port: 9000
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 2
          periodSeconds: 3
          failureThreshold: 1
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /actuator/health
            port: 9000
          initialDelaySeconds: 20
          timeoutSeconds: 2
          periodSeconds: 8
          failureThreshold: 1
```

Comment: How long does it take the spring boot app to startup and respond? I've seen spring boot apps take a lot longer than 10 seconds.

Comment: Have you also verified without livenessprobe whether the /actuator/health is actually working.

Comment: I don't think it's a good practice to use the same actuator endpoint for both live & readiness probes...

Comment: try to hit the URL from the postman and check first if it is working. Or override management.endpoints.web.base-path to some value in application.properties and try that url.

Comment: Thank you guys, I can access from postman and I get the result.
I redefine the configuration and still not work.

Comment: You redefined what to what? Post more details as it's still not know where is the issue.

Comment: I remove the "timeoutSeconds", "failureThreshold" and set the configuration like this: initialDelaySeconds: 60, periodSeconds: 10

Answer (score 2):

Although I am replying a bit late. But I think my implementation will help people in future to implement kubernetes readiness / liveness probe for spring boot applications.

Description of my docker image

1. Built from alpine linux
2. Spring boot 2 application, can be accessible only via SSL
3. Spring boot actuator implemented /actuator/health which returns {"status":"UP"}

**So I cannot use httpGet option of kubernetes, as it uses http protocol only.**

That is why I create a small shell script "check-if-healthy.sh" as part of docker image to know the status

```
check-if-healthy.sh
===================
curl -k https://localhost:8888/actuator/health | grep '"status":"UP"' > /dev/null && exit 0 || exit 1
```

Please note you need to add this script into docker image, so that it will be available in running container and accessible to kubernetes, As kubernetes will fire **"docker exec /bin/ash /home/config-server/check-if-healthy."** like this

```
COPY docker/check-if-healthy.sh /home/config-server/check-if-healthy.sh
```

And then used "exec" option of kubernetes readiness probe to call the script like this.

```
      readinessProbe:
        exec:
          command:
            - /bin/ash
            - /home/config-server/check-if-healthy.sh
        initialDelaySeconds: 5
        timeoutSeconds: 1
        failureThreshold: 50
      livenessProbe:
        exec:
          command:
            - /bin/ash
            - /home/config-server/check-if-healthy.sh
        initialDelaySeconds: 5
        timeoutSeconds: 1
        failureThreshold: 50
```

Comment: Why are your SpringBoot application inside a container securized with SSL? My though is that this is no needed in a containerized enviroment, you can rely the SSLt o the front proxy of the container and not in the application itself

Comment: Hello David, You are probably right. It is not required if application is not exposed directly. I just did it just to have extra level of security.